# Custom Images in Wordpress not showing the correct sizes inside the attachment select

Tags: wordpress, image

I have added some custom images to my functions.php and they are working as expected.

But I don't know why, when you try to select any of them from the ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS to add it to a post, all the custom images shows the same size than the Large Image: 640 x 360, so if you add one to the post, all of them are added with that size instead of his own size, with the exception of the Square one.

I have seen in wp-includes/media-template.php around line 954 how the code of the select is generated trying to figure out if the problem is in my conde inside functions.php, but it is correct. I suspect the problem has to do with javascript because this line:

```
var size = data.sizes['<?php echo esc_js( $value ); ?>'];
```

It seems the sizes of my custom images are not included in the data variable.

Please, could someone put light in my issue? It's really weird!

Just in case, here below you have the code I wrote inside my functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'post',             1110,   0, true );
    add_image_size( 'news',              768,   0, true );
    add_image_size( 'square',        500, 500, true );


    // Register the three useful image sizes for use in Add Media modal
    add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'wpshout_custom_sizes' );
    function wpshout_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
        return array_merge( $sizes, array(
            'post' => __('Post'),
            'news' => __('News'),
            'square' => __('Square'),
        ) );
    }
```

Comment: Hi again, I have found that even the normal images setted inside Setting/Media appear in that selector with a different size than they are supposed to be. But when you upload an image, it is well cropped and all the different sizes are uploaded along wth the original one in the uploads folder. Pretty Weird! Any idea?

Comment: There is no one to help me with this thing? Please, any Help?